# How to prove that the volume, as defined in beginner calculus, is invariant under rigid motion?

Tags: calculus, integration, geometry

1. Usually, in the applications of integration, the volume of a solid $S$ that lies between $x=a$ and $x=b$ is defined by
   $$V(S)=\int_a^b A(x)\,dx,$$
   where $A(x)$ is the area of the vertical cross-sectional area of $S$ through $x$.
2. Let $S'$ be obtained from $S$ by a 90 degree rotation. From the above definition, if $S'$ lies between $x=c$ and $x=d$, we have
   $$V(S')=\int_c^d B(x)\,dx,$$
   where $B(x)$ is the area of the vertical cross-sectional area of $S'$ through $x$.
3. Since the volume have to be invariant under rigid motion, $V(S)$ have to be equal $V(S')$. Or, what amounts to the same thing, $V(S )$ should be equal to
   $$\int_c^d B(y)\,dy,$$
   where $B(y)$ is the area of the horizontal cross-sectional area of $S$ through $y$.

How to prove that this is the case? In other words, how to prove that horizontal and vertical slicing give equivalent definitions for the volume? (It seems this fact is freely used is calculus books without further explanation.)

Comment: Have been introduced to the idea of using Jacobian in multivariable calculus? If yes, just use the rotation matrix for the appropriate rotation that you are doing. Note that for pure rotations, $|det(J)|=1,$ where J is the Jacobian matrix corresponding to that rotation.

Comment: The fact that $x,y$-, $x,z$-, and $y,z$-slicings give the same result can be understood as an expression of Fubini's theorem. For other rigid motions I agree with MathRookie that the Jacobian determinant is a good way to go about it.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @MathRookie2204 ... but how do you prove that the determinant preserves the volume?  (noting there are various different ways to start by defining the determinant, but I challenge you to make a well-defined definition for which this argument is not circular)

Comment: Also, how do we even define *volume*? That's an important question here. If we use the Lebesgue measure, some measure-theoretic work has to be done to show the determinant gives the correct scale factor. See [section 2.8, here](https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch2.pdf)

Comment: I agree with Lemmon that the question as you've asked is exactly Fubini's theorem, whether the Lebesgue or Riemann versions. Calculus books do not go into it because Calculus books skirt past many deficiencies in definition or proof, with the intent of allowing students to concentrate on absorbing the massive amount of new concepts that come with the course instead of technical minutia. Anything they can pass over, relying on the students' general intuitions to get them to accept it, they will.

Answer (score 1):

*How to prove that the volume, as defined in beginner calculus, is invariant under rigid motion?*

Considering the Stewart's definition (used in the original post) and without assuming any other result, it seems it's not a easy (if possible) task.

However, looking through several books I found the Apostol's approach, according to which it's possible to avoid multivariable calculus by using Cavalieri's principle (which allows us to relate areas to volumes without double integrals):

> **Cavalieri's principle:** If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are two solids such that $\operatorname{area}(S_1\cap \alpha)\leq \operatorname{area}(S_2\cap \alpha)$ for every plane $\alpha$ perpendicular to a given line, then $\operatorname{volume}(S_1)\leq \operatorname{volume}(S_2)$.

In this case, the volume is defined axiomatically (as explained [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/a/26719/13585)). Then, the formulas
$$V(S)=\int_a^b A(x)\,dx\quad\text{and}\quad V(S)=\int_c^d B(y)\,dy$$
are theorems. Apostol's definition of integral, and thus his approach to the volume formulas, uses step functions. However, if we assume that the cross-sectional area function is continuous (which is the case in the main cases), it seems it's possible to adapt the argument for the context of Stewart's definition of integral:

Given a solid $S$ and a line $L$, introduce a coordinate axis along $L$ and call it the $u$-axis. Let $A(u)$ be the area of the cross section cut by a plane perpendicular to $L$ at the point $u$. Suppose that $S$ lies between the planes $u=a$ and $u=b$.

> **Theorem:** Let $S$ be a solid whose cross-sectional area function $A$ (defined as above) is continuous on $[a, b]$. Then,
> $$\operatorname{volume}(S)=\int_a^bA(u)\, du.$$

*Remark:* The generic $u$-axis can be the usal $x$ or $y$ axes. In other words, horizontal as well as vertical slicing are allowed. Also, since the $u$-axis is arbitrary, the position of $S$ with respect to the reference axis does not matter, that is, the volume is invariant under rigid motion.

*Proof:* Divide $[a,b]$ into $n$ subintervals $[u_0,u_1]$, $[u_1,u_2]$, ..., $[u_{n-1},u_n]$ of equal width $\Delta u$, where $a=u_0< u_1< u_2< \cdots< u_{n-1}< u_n=b$.

By the continuity of $f$, there exists $\tilde{u}_i\in[u_{i-1},u_i]$ such that
$$A(\tilde{u}_i)\leq A(u),\quad\forall\ u\in[u_{i-1},u_i].\tag{1}$$

Over the interval $[u_{i-1},u_i]$, construct the right cylinder with height $\Delta u$ and cross-sectional area $A(\tilde{u}_i)$. Let $S_1$ be the solid formed by the union of these $n$ constructed cylinders. By Cavalieri's principle, $(1)$ implies that
$$\operatorname{volume}(S_1)\leq \operatorname{volume}(S).\tag{2}$$

Analogously, again by the continuity of $f$, there exists $\hat{u}_i\in[u_{i-1},u_i]$ such that
$$A(u)\leq A(\hat{u}_i),\quad\forall\ u\in[u_{i-1},u_i].\tag{3}$$

Now, over the interval $[u_{i-1},u_i]$, construct the right cylinder with height $\Delta u$ and cross-sectional area $A(\hat{u}_i)$. Let $S_2$ be the solid formed by the union of these $n$ constructed cylinders. By Cavalieri's principle, $(3)$ implies that
$$\operatorname{volume}(S)\leq \operatorname{volume}(S_2).\tag{4}$$

From $(2)$ and $(4)$, we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^n A(\tilde{u}_i)\Delta u\leq \operatorname{volume}(S) \leq \sum_{i=1}^n A(\hat{u}_i)\Delta u$$

Taking the limit with $n\to\infty$, we get

$$\int_a^b A(u)\,du \leq \operatorname{volume}(S) \leq \int_a^b A(u)\,du,$$
which gives the desired equality. $\square$

*Remark:* Given that Cavalieri's principle is assumed to be true, the same proof works in the context of Stewart's definition of integral (for continuous cross-sectional area).